# Node server.js does not get env variables from elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-codebuild

I try to launch a node.js project with AWS CodeBuild on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I put my env variables in the Elastic Beanstalk Configuration under Software Configuration. After that I deployed my project to Elastic Beanstalk and my server.js has no env variables.

I implemented a console.log(process.env) at the top of my server.js but there are no env variables that I filled in Elastic Beanstalk configuration. I visited the Elastic Beanstalk Logs.

Also my logs show me this:

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)

npm ERR! Linux 4.9.43-17.39.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.1-linux-
x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.1-linux-
x64/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! xxxxxxx start: `NODE_ENV=production node server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xxxxxxx start script 'NODE_ENV=production node server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the xxxxxxx package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     NODE_ENV=production node server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs xxxxxxx
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mapify-ssr
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Check [Environment Property Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console) are you using restricted characters or exceeding overall max size ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu Thanks for the hint. I checked them and they contain no restricted characters and are really small.

Comment: No error in events ? Rebuilding the environment may help

Comment: @GabrielBleu I just started the rebuild of the environment.

Comment: @GabrielBleu Still no env variables in the log output